# MongoDB, finding users nearby but removing blocked users without affecting limit

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to fetch 100 users that are near by but I want to remove the current blocked users so that if there is say 10 blocked users the returned users wouldn't be 90 but 100...

I wrote this query (using mongojs for node):

```
db.users.find({location: {$near: [lng, lat]}, _id:{$ne: ObjectId('4ffeff845d46eaf1aa000002')}}, function(err, docs) {
    if(!err) {
        res.json(users);
    };

}).limit(100);
```

That works but only for one blocked user, I have a field in a users document so that the user can block multiple users:

```
{
    ...
    blockedUsers: ['4ffeff845d46eaf1aa000002', '4ffeff845d46eaf1aa000012',....]
}
```

I have tired to add an array of ObjectId's after the $ne but it does nothing, I also tired having a variable with all the ObjectId's split with || and that failed to work too.

My question is how would I go about querying mongodb for the nearest users limited to 100, removing the users that are blocked so it actually returns 100 instead of minus the blocked users if I was to remove them after I did the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check out the $nin operator? 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24nin

Comment: Thanks I must have missed that!